# What is the story of Harihara?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, identification-request

I know Harihara is a combined form of Vishnu and Shiva, but Is any stories about this form described in any scriptures?

---

<sup>(Note: It is not a duplicate of Harihara litearture. That question is just asked about Harihara's concept, but my answer is about the story.)</sup>

Comment: I think it's duplicate of this question: [Harihara literature](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28784/647)

Comment: Mahishi , sister of Mahishasura by an intense tapas ,gets a boon from Lord Brahma , that only a son begotten by 2 Parama Purushas (Hari and Hara)
should only be able to kill her . According to her,  such an event can never happen . But anything is possible for Supreme God whose powers are infinite. So Lord  HariHara is born to Hari and Hara to annihilate Mahishi.Does the question ask for scriptural reference to this story?

Comment: @Athrey actually you referring Ayyapa. Lord Harihara is also known as Sankaranarayana (half-vishnu and half-shiva).

Comment: yes . I mistook HariHaratmaja for Harihara. As per Sthalapuran of HariHareshwara temple Karnataka ,Guhasura obtained a boon from Brahma, that  Shiva or Visnu canot singly kill him, So Vishnu and Shiva together took The fused form Harihara, to kill Guhasura.But Sthalapuran of Shankaranrayana seems to be different. When two Naga kings sanga and paduma argues over Shiva/Vishnu supremacy, Gomati amba does tapas over needle(aadi tapas) and invokes Shankaranrayana to show, Shiva and Vishnu are no different. This story may occur in kurma purana. (mostly it dificult to locate sthala legend in puranas)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It's just about concept of Harihara. But, I'm just asking for the story of Harihara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two Chapters in the Vamana Purana where Shiva and Vishnu are both shown displaying their HariHara Forms.

> **[Vamana Purana Ch 67](https://archive.org/details/vamanapuranavaishnavaupapuranasanskritenglishocr/page/n385/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

> **[Vamana Purana Ch 62](https://archive.org/details/vamanapuranavaishnavaupapuranasanskritenglishocr/page/n347/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

You can read the stories behind them from the chapters provided.

Answer (score 3):

I found about why Shiva and Vishnu become Harihara from [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502226.html) of
Skanda Purana.

> 8-10. I shall suggest a means to be placed before you all who have taken resort to excellent Dharma (righteousness).
>
> Once devotees of Śiva had a great dispute. They quarrelled with the devotees of Keśava. They wanted to gain victory over one another. Thereupon, even as his devotees were watching, Lord Rudra assumed a wonderful form with an idea of bringing about peace with the Gaṇas of Viṣṇu. With the halves of each boḍy he assumed the form of Hari-Hara.