# Is any name of Vishnu Siva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, name, vishnu-sahasranama

Vishnu has several names over scriptures such as Sahasranamam.

Is any name of Vishnu is mentioned as Siva?

Comment: You check kuttralam in Tamilnadu, were Vishnu idol has shrunk by agasthiyar to shiv ling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Lord Vishnu is also called Shiva in few versions of Vishnu Sahasranama. For example, Shiva appears as 27th name in [Vishnu Sahasranama found in Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13135.htm):

> 17 सर्वः शर्वः **शिवः** सथाणुर भूतादिर निधिर अव्ययः
>        संभवॊ भावनॊ भर्ता परभवः परभुर ईश्वरः
>
> 17 sarvaḥ śarvaḥ **śivaḥ** sthāṇur bhūtādir nidhir avyayaḥ
>        saṃbhavo bhāvano bhartā prabhavaḥ prabhur īśvaraḥ

[Wikipedia: Vishnu Sahasranama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Sahasranama) also mentions this in *The Thousand Names of Lord Vishnu* section:

> 27    शिवः    shivah