# Is the Vaikhanasa commentary on the Brahma Sutras available in English?

Tags: vaishnavism, vedanta, translation-request, brahma-sutras, vaikhanasa

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6896/36), one of the early movements that was important in the development of Vaishnavism was the ancient Pancharatra movement, whose sacred texts consisted of detailed procedures to worship the sage Narayana, an ancient incarnation of Vishnu. Since the Pancharatra texts originated from Narayana himself, they are followed by pretty much all mainstream Vaishnava Sampradayas, whether Sri Vaishnavas, Madhvas, Gaudiya Vaishnavas, etc. But as I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3977/36) there's another group of Vishnu-worshippers who worship Vishnu according toan entirely different set of texts, the Vaikhanasas.  They form a tiny minority, but they run a lot of famous Vishnu temples including the world-renowned Tirumala Venkateshwara temple.

In any case, compared to mainstream Vaishnavas, Vaikhanasas put less emphasis on Vedantic philosophy and more emphasis on rituals; Vaikhanasa doctrines are more about the construction and worship of idols and the like.   But like the vast majority of Hindus, they still subscribe to the Vedanta school of philosophy.  And the defining text of the Vedanta school is the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa which summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads.

And so like most sects, the Vaikhanasas have a commentary on the Brahma Sutras.  It was written by Srinivasa Dikshitar, a 13th century Vaikhanasa priest of Tirupati, and it's known as the Lakshmi-Visistadvaita Bhashya.  Its philosophy is similar to the Visistadvaita philosophy of the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya, with one important difference: whereas Ramanujacharya believed that Brahman/Vishnu was "Visista" or qualified by souls and matter, Srinivasa Dikshitar believed that Brahman was qualified by Lakshmi.  In that way it's similar to the Lingayat philosophy of Shakti Visistadvaita, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6621/36), except Shiva and Shakti are replaced by Vishnu and Lakshmi.

But my question is, has Srinivasa Dikshitar's commentary on the Brahma Sutras available in English?  [This excerpt](https://ia600206.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/8/items/svuorientaljourn015493mbp/svuorientaljourn015493mbp_tif.zip&file=svuorientaljourn015493mbp_tif/svuorientaljourn015493mbp_0049.tif&scale=8&rotate=0) from a journal paper by D. Sridhara Babu says it was published in Sanskrit in Telegu script in 1896:

> Srinivasa Dikshita's commentary on the [Brahma Sutras] together with Sunderaraja Bhattacharya's sub-commentary was first published in Telegu characters in Madras in 1996. This work has been edited by Srinivasa Tatacharya and Vasudeva Bhattacharya.

But is it still in print or available online, and has it ever been translated into English?  The reason I ask is that I want to compare it to Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya, his commentary on the Brahma Sutras, and see how these two flavors of Visistadvaita differ on their interpretation.