# What do scriptures say regarding Immigration & Emigration?

Tags: scripture, brahmins, dharma-shastras

For example, one popular rule that is believed to be scripturally imposed is that brahmanas can't participate in sea voyages. **Where is it mentioned that such journey is prohibited**?

Comment: Related [Why are Tirupati temple priests restricted from traveling overseas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14987/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer In the Tirupati example, are these references directly from the Vedas?

Comment: Not Sure, i think Dharma Sutras. But Mylavarapu Srinivasa Rao, a scholar from Andhra, says as it wasn't possible to do Sandhya vandanam and other Brahmin rites on Ships, they included this rule. He says this rule doesn't fit for today's world.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Travel by ship was also forbidden because human refuse was emptied into the sea which is a gross sin. Polluting waters is fordbidden in Hinduism. Other reasons are having to eat forbidden foodstuffs. It is not just the difficulty in observing sandhya.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Everything need not be mentioned in the vedas. It is incorrect to discard ancient wisdom because one is unable to find a vedic reference. 1. Vedas are infinite. The portion of the veda available to us is infinitesimal 2. Hindu dharma is encapsulated in sruti (veda), smriti, purana, samhita, as well as janachara (the path trod my knowledgeable elders).

Answer (score 9):

**Where is it mentioned that such journey is prohibited?**

**[Chapter 22](https://archive.org/stream/BrihanNaradiyaPurana/brhan_naradiya_purana#page/n375/mode/2up), "Varnasramavidhi**" (Rules to be followed by four Varnas) of **Brihan Naradiya Purana** states "Samudrayatra" (voyage over sea) is prohibited for Dvijas (twice borns) in Kali Yuga.

This chapter mentions various deeds which are prohibited in Kali Yuga.

> समुद्रयात्रास्वीकारः कमण्डलुविधारणम् । द्वीजानामसवर्णसुवा
>   कन्यास्पयमस्तथा ॥ १३
>
> samudrayātrāsvīkāraḥ kamaṇḍaluvidhāraṇam । dvījānāmasavarṇasuvā
>   kanyāspayamastathā ॥ 13
>
> Undertaking sea voyages, the carrying of  kamandalu (waterpot) ,  the
>   marriage  of dvija (twice-born) men with damsels unequal in Varna...

After mentioning all examples, *verse 23 (b)* says all these practices must be shunned in age of Kali.

Comment: Did you also find anything regarding Immigration? for example, if a Dvija is born abroad are they allowed to undertake sea voyage for coming back to India?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Above verse says Samudrayatra Swikaraha.. (Accepting sea voyage is prohibited). I think it is true for both journeys. Since it is only available in Sanskrit, i read only some verses in that chapter. But i will try to update the answer with other details.

Comment: Then how Hinduism went to Indonesia, Malaysia Singapore, etc?

Comment: @NarayanaSharma It could be possible this smriti was of later day. Ancient kingdoms had trade relations with even Arabia and beyond. It's not possible to travel on *Uttarapatha* (Grand Trunk Road) and Silk Road all the way to Arabia.