# How to recover from lost caste status after crossing an ocean?

Tags: caste-system, sin, dharma-shastras, prayaschitta

Based on what I know, the most loss of Hindutva that can happen is loss of caste (which would include the right to cremate one's parents), for example for crossing the ocean.

From [here](https://www.dailyo.in/variety/hindus-caste-nris-abroad-brahmins-dalits-ramayana-sea-trade-kalapani-mughals/story/1/15103.html):

> Baudhayana Dharma-sutra, composed about 2,000 years ago, maybe earlier, lists this "Samudrolanghana" or "Sagarollanghana" as the first of many reasons for loss of castes (II.1.2.2).

Are there sacraments to recover lost caste status for *Samudrolanghana* or other reasons?

Comment: make it little clear

Comment: Could u pls be kind enough to elaborate "crossing the ocean"..do u mean if someone goes to US or other country which is another side of the ocean he ll loose his caste?

Comment: look up "kala pani"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kala_pani_(taboo) The Tirupati Temple does not allow a priest who has crossed the seas to enter the temple's sanctum sanctorum.[16]

In 2007, the ascension of Sugunendra Tirtha to the Udupi Krishna Temple was opposed by some seers, because he had visited foreign countries, thus committing the offence of saagarolanga (crossing the sea).[17] In 2008, a court verdict formally allowed his ascension.[18] In 2012, both he and his opponent Vishwesha Teertha announced fasts to pressure each other on the issue.[19]"

Comment: Looks like you are answering the title question yourself by pointing to a reference. "are there sacraments to recover lost caste status" - this should be the title question.

Comment: feel free to reformat @sv.

Comment: Related: [Why are Tirupati temple priests restricted from traveling overseas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14987/2995)

Comment: Related [What do scriptures say regarding Immigration & Emigration?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17448/3500)

Answer (score 4):

By undertaking a sea voyage one losses caste. Such people should be avoided at Sraddhas as said in Smritis like Manu etc.

The Baudhayana Dharma Sutras (BDS) also gives the remedy of that sin.

> 1 Next, the sins causing loss of caste: stealing a Brahmin’s property
>   or a deposit; undertaking a sea voyage; bearing false witness with regard to
>   land; trading in all sorts of merchandise;  serving S ´udras;
>   fathering children by a S ´udra woman; and becoming a child of a S
>   ´udra.* When people have done any one of these,  **they should eat a
>   little at every fourth mealtime ; bathe at dawn, noon, and dusk; and
>   remain standing during the day and seated at night. In three years
>   they wipe off their sin.**
>
> **BDS 2.2.1-10**

> **Fourth mealtime**--- two mealtimes a day are acknowledged for humans, morning and evening. Eating every fourth mealtime amounts to
>   eating one day in the morning and the next day in the evening, thus
>   skipping two mealtimes between meals

As additional information I am quoting from the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) which states that Samudra Yatra is prohibited in Kali Yuga:

> **Kali Yuga Nishiddhas:**
>
> **The following are the avoidable and unnecessary acts of Kali Yuga
>   viz. Samudra Yatra,** carrying of Kamandulu to misdirect the Public ,
>   remarriages, begetting children from husband’s brothers; Go Vadha;
>   Mamsa Bhakshana at Shraddhas; performing vivaha to a physically imm
>   ature girl; Chira kaala Brahmacharitwa; Naramedha Ashwamedha Gomedha
>   Yagna; Madya Paana, Abhakshya Bhakshana, Apeya paana, Agamyaagamana
>   or wandering aimlesly Rahasya Prayascittha, Devata Puja and Pashubali
>   for evil ends; Kula Bhrashtata; Extreme Profiteering and narrow
>   mindedness.

Comment: this is absurd of course.  since the remedy is more or less impossible - if you lose caste you have lost it for good.  thats why apparently tirupati will not take back priests who have been abroad but the priests don't care https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/sunday-times/deep-focus/Migration-new-mantra-for-Indian-priests/articleshow/45509380.cms  hinduism itself may become a dollar denominated American religion.

Comment: america certainly qualifies and hindu priests seem to be beating down the doors to lose caste status.  As "American Hindus" become dominant, they'll change the rules. @YDS

Comment: Any clear definition of "**undertaking a sea voyage**".. What is the exact distance for this?? ..Rama & Hanuman also crossed ocean to reach in Lanka..isn't it? In Kanyakumari, people take sea voyage for a short distance to visit Vivekananda Rock Memorial..now i wonder if they visit it to loose their caste???

Comment: "In three years they wipe off their sin" - so until 3 years they are casteless? In those 3 years, rules of which varna apply to them?

Comment: this is absurd of course --- Yes that's a difficult remedy, that's alright..@SK ; In those 3 years, rules of which varna apply to them? ---- i am not sure..sometimes it is said, that a Brahmin becomes a Sudra.. so then we know the exact status.. sometimes (like here) nothing is mentioned.. so we don't really know if they become like Vratyas (who are completely excluded from Arya community and all the duties) or whether they assume the next caste.. If a Sudra losses his caste then obviously he becomes an outcaste but i don't think we can say that for a Brahmin..@sv

Comment: Where can I read BDS in English?

Comment: You can read from this page: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/baudh%C4%81yana-dharmas%C5%ABtra @NarayanaSharma