# Is crossing the ocean (Samudrollanghana) a taboo in Hinduism?

Tags: dharma-shastras

As per the below wiki link, crossing the ocean is considered a taboo in hinduism.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kala_pani_(taboo)

The link gives quote from a dharmashastra which prohibits crossing the ocean.  I am not sure how this is interpreted by commentators. Is it true that crossing the ocean is considered taboo? Does this have strong basis in the scriptures?

Edit: I am looking for all the references from scriptures which prohibit crossing the ocean.

Comment: Rama, Lakshmana, Sita, Hanuman have all crossed the ocean in the Ramayana. But I dont remember Valmiki objecting to it.

Comment: It has been already shown by Rickross that because sandhyavandana can not be done while crossing the ocean (by ship of course), it was restricted.

Comment: @commonman Is mine a duplicate question?

Comment: I am not that interested in branding Qs as duplicates.

Comment: Donn't take myths too seriously.

Comment: See answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/how-to-recover-from-lost-caste-status-after-crossing-an-ocean