# Worship of Shree Ramanuja while he was in his body?

Tags: vishnu, rituals, worship, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya

Shree Ramanuja authorised worships of his forms in three murthies.
When he leaves Melakotai in Karnataka,a vighra is made and Ramanujar embraces it and gives it back. This is called "Thamar Ukantha Thirumeni" in Tamil.
In SriPerumPuthuthur (his birth place), his disciples make a vighra and he authorises it by giving his Sakti. This is called as "ThAnukantha Thirumeni".
The third is His own body worshipped in Srirangam. This is called as "ThAneyAna Thirumeni".

Was he worshipped before he left for Parampadam?

Comment: I know only two of them which is the third one. The two statues are shown in this answer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8032/489

Comment: Focus of my question is when did worship of Ramanuja as deity started, even before he left for Lord's abode or later?

Comment: Okay, I know only two statues of Bhagwad Ramanujacharya that are totally divine in nature like the Bhavishyadacharya staute, and The statue that he gave to his students before leaving his body. That's why I asked which other authorized statue you are talking about, but now that you have mentioned some unknown statues your question is more interesting.