# Do scriptures mention about Srimad Madhvacharya being an avatar of Lord Vayu?

Tags: avatars, dvaita, madhvacharya, vayu

It is believed by his followers that Srimad Ananda Teertha (a.k.a [Madhvacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhvacharya)) was the third incarnation of Vayu (MukhyaprAna), the previous two were:

1. Hanuman (Treta yuga)
2. Bheema Sena (Dwapara yuga)

It is claimed that Madhvacharya had met Vyasa in the Badarika ashrama in Himalayas and learned deeper meanings of shastras there. Later he had toured the entire country towards the mission of fighting against the doctrines of maayavada. Also against non-Hindu forces. Later he disappeared with his physical body.

Do scriptures mention anything about Madhvacharya being an incarnation of Vayu?

Or is there any mention in his biographies about the same ?

Comment: " doctrines of mayavada and **other** non hindu forces". Since when Advaita is considered as Non Hindu?

Comment: @TheDestroyer they believe that it is covered buddhism. Hence he spoke against this and buddhist ideology.

Comment: But that doesn't make Advaita, non Hindu. They may feel like that. Your question should represent neutrality. Advaita is pure Hindu Vedanta Philosophy. So, you can remove word "other".

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes its their belief only. As per them its vayu incarnation. As per Srivaishnava ramanuja is adi shesha and as per advaita sankara is shiva :)

Comment: Not only as per Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam but the people who believe in Alwars, believe in Divinity of Bhawad Ramanujacharya his Vigraha was given by Swami Sadhgopan to Swami Madhurakavi Alwar. Which was carried forward(is available to this day in Alwar thirunagri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alwarthirunagari_Temple) http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8031/489. Regarding Madhavacharya only he believes that he is an avatar of Vayu and Hanuman.

Comment: This is obviously something that different sects of Hinduism disagree on, so I'm closing your question for the time being.  If you want to revise your question so that it can be given a factual answer like "Do followers of Madhvacharya consider him to be an incarnation of Vayu?" or "Are there any scriptures which say that Madhvacharya is an incarnation of Vayu?" then I'd be happy to reopen it.

Comment: You can easily change ur Q to-"Are there any scriptures which mention Madhavachrya as an incarnation of Vayu?" In fact I had a similar Q about Adi Shankara

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "This is obviously something that different sects of Hinduism disagree on" - Trying to understand how is that a reason to close a question? If a BG shlokha is interpreted differently by different acharyas, is that also a reason to close a question?

Comment: @Rickross "any scriptures which mention Madhvacharya" - what scriptures were written after Madhvacharya? I don't see how using the word "scriptures" suddenly makes it a valid question. What it makes it is an impossible to answer question! :)

Comment: @sv. If a question asked "Is Adi Shankaracharya's interpretation of this Gita verse correct or is Ramanujacharya's interpretation correct?" that would absolutely be reason to close it.  Questions about what a certain sect believes about a subject, or questions that ask what scripture says about a subject, are fine, but questions that ask what sect is right about a subject is not really what our site is for.

Comment: @sv. Well, Hindu scripture contains prophesies of various future events and incarnations, so it's entirely possible that Hindu scripture contains prophesies of Madhvacharya's birth.

Comment: @sv Many Puranas talk about future events ..For ex there r many Puranas that talk about Adi Shankara..So,that is the only way i thought it was possible to make this Q a valid one..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "Is Adi Shankaracharya's interpretation of this Gita verse correct or is Ramanujacharya's interpretation correct? - That would absolutely be reason to close it." - Agree 100% but that's not what OP asked here. Before you closed it, he asked: "Was Srimad Madhvacharya an avatar of Lord Vayu?" This is like asking [Is Buddha is an avatara of Vishnu](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/180), it really doesn't matter if various acharyas disagree on that. This is what I was trying to point out...

Answer (score 3):

Madhvacharya has quoted the Balittha Sukta ([Rig Veda 1.141.1-5](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01141.htm)) at the end of his commentary on the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad
to assert himself to be an incarnation of Vayu:

> *balittha tad vapusedhayi darsatam devasya bhargah sahaso yato ajani* |
>
> *yadimupahvarate sadhate matir-rtasya dhena anayanta sasrutah* || 1 ||
>
> *prkso vapuh pitumannitya asaye dvitiyamasaptasivasu matrsu*  |
>
> *trtiyamasya vrsabhasya dohase dasapramatim janayantayosanah* || 2 ||
>
> *niryadim budhnanmahisasya varpasa isanasah savasa krantasurayah*  |
>
> *yadimanupradivo madhva adhave guhasantam matarisva mathayati* || 3 ||
>
> *prayatpituh paramanniyateparyaprksudho virudho dansu rohati*  |
>
> *ubhayasya janusam yadinvata adidyabistho abhavadhdhrna sucih* || 4 ||
>
> *adinmatrravisadyasva sucirahimsyamana urviya vivavrdhe*  |
>
> *anuyatpurva aruhastanajuvoni navyasisva varasu dhavate* || 5 ||

After quoting the above Suktam, Madhvacharya goes on to comments on it as follows:

> The three forms of Vayu which have the auspicious qualities of 'krida' (sporting), etc., are well described in the Vedic texts -- as being of the essence of strength (bala), full of pious knowledge (jnana). They protect the world, impart divine knowledge and are extremely holy and sacred. All the three forms appeared in the world per the desire of the Supreme Being. Just like the main (mula) form, these forms also are full of strength and knowledge (with no diminution during incarnation). The first form of Hanuman takes the words of Shri Rama (to Sita). It also teaches the precious and auspicious knowledge from Mula Ramayana to its disciples, for their salvation. The second form, as Bhima, is the main destroyer (of evil forces of the Kauravas and others). The third form of Madhva has composed this bhasya (Brhadaranyaka) to please the Supreme Lord - Shri Hari.
>
> The word '*hanu*' means knowledge and hence, Hanuman is refered as '*Mati*' in the Sukta by Madhvacharya. The words "*rtasya dhena anayanta sasrutah*" mean that Hanuman carried the message (*dhena*) of Shri Rama (*rta*) who is always Eternal or Changeless and who is the essence of Truth, to Sita.'*rtasya dhena anayanta sasrutah*' can also mean that he taught the immutable and eternal truths such as the Mula Ramayana (the original Ramayana composed of a hundred crore slokas, given by Lord Hayagriva to Brahma) to his disciples for their salvation. "*prkso vapuh*" describes the Bhima incarnation. '*bhima*' has the same meaning as "*a saye saptasivasu matrsu*." 'Bhima' is "one who has all knowledge of the sacred texts" (sastras). The expansion in support of this is given as 'bhrtah mah yena sa bhimah' -- bhrtah (supported, repository of); *mah*, from the same root as *pra-mah*, (sources) of valid knowledge, or pramanas, yena sah (from whom). 'ma-tr' means all the valid sastra texts. These are the four Vedas -- Rig, Yajur, Sama and Atharva, along with itihasa, purana and pancaratra. '*saye*' means "well versed in." Bhima is well versed in all the seven sources of valid knowledge given above. The words 'trtiyamasya vrsabhasya dohase' describe Shri Madhva. The word '*madhva*' means "the author of '*va*' (sastras) which give '*madhu*' (bliss). Similarly '*tirtha*' means the same as '*va*'. Thus 'Ananda Tirtha' and 'Madhva' mean the same thing. It is stated that anyone who understands correctly the reference to the three forms of Vayu described in this Sukta, will understand all the Vedas correctly and will secure valid knowledge (*tattva-jnana*) with the blessings of Vayu.

The Balittha Sukta has also been quoted by Madhvacharya in his other works. These works are as follows:

- Shri Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya
- Commentaries on the Taittiriya Upanishad, Aitareya Upanishad and the Chandogya Upanishad.
- Brahma Sutras
- Anu Vyakhyana
- Vishnu Tattva Vinirnaya
- Tantra Sara Sangraha

Note that this interpretation of the Balittha Sukta is limited to the Madhvas only as neither traditional commentators on the Vedas such as Sayanacharya nor modern translators of the Rig-Veda such as H.H. Wilson, believe the Balittha Sukta to be a hymn dedicated to Vayu. The Sukta is generally regarded to be dedicated to Agni.

([Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20171112144931/http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Vedas/Balittha_Sukta_and_Madhvacarya.htm))

**Note**: Personally, I disagree with Madhvacharya's interpretation (and assertion of himself being Vayu's avatara) of the Balittha Sukta. Therefore, this answer doesn't represent my views.

Comment: I havent read your note first then i voted for this.. I did a mistake by upvoting this answer now its forzen.. Please dont post anything which you dont agree..  its gives bad impression.. for question and also the answer you had written deeming that as invalid, its like saying the above is just information which i dont agree.. the above answer is invalid then why answer first

Comment: You don't need to believe to answer a question. This forum has many atheists who answer from scriptures even if they disagree. Remember, this site is not a Hindu site. It is a site about Hinduism. There is a difference. @PrasannaR

Answer (score 1):

Yes many many Scriptures do, mostly the verses are lost but some are available and trackable in current Editions of Garud Puran, Skanda Puran, Padma Puran, Bhavishya Puran as well as Valmiki Ramayan and Balitha Shuktam

Answer (score 0):

Not all Hindus are aware of Srimad Madhvacharya and his existence. The followers who believe in him being the third avatar of Vayu are known as Madhvaas, a community that follows Madhvacharya's Dvaita philosophy. 
There is no reference of Srimad Madhvacharya being the third incarnation of Vayu in the scriptures. 
To learn more about Madhvacharya, I recommend reading “Madhwavijaya” by Narayana Panditha. It is a very informative book, so I definitely encourage you to check it out!

Comment: Can you give some quotes from author regarding this question from the book you mentioned if possible.

Comment: How can you say with conviction that no scripture talks about him?

Comment: Of course, there are scriptures which talk about them. However, none of them refer to Srimad Madhvacharya as being the third avatar of Vayu. I received the information from multiple other websites. I do not have all of the scriptures which reference him with me. Therefore I am going off what information I have. If you wish to explore this topic further, you can do so. You are right, I am not completely sure but this is the most I could find.