# Is Vayu identical to Pavan in Dvaita philosophy?

Tags: identification-request, rebirth, dvaita, madhvacharya, vayu

Is the *Vayu deva (Mukhya Prana)* in the [Devata taratamya of Acharya Madhwa](https://dvaitavedanta.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/taratamya-of-sri-madhvacharya/) identical with *Pavan deva* or is he someone different?

Comment: Are you asking this because of statement "Lord Brahma and Vayu are the top most in the list of souls who are subject to bondage." from the link? If yes then please add it in question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do scriptures mention about Srimad Madhvacharya being an avatar of Lord Vayu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/do-scriptures-mention-about-srimad-madhvacharya-being-an-avatar-of-lord-vayu)

Comment: @Krishna Shweta No. My doubt is not due to the statement  "Lord Brahma and Vayu are the top most in the list of souls who are subject to bondage." mentioned in the blog. I suspect that Vayu mentioned in taratamya is not pavan dev. I needed clarification.

Comment: It is pavana deva, however in Madhva's philosophy, he isn't just a normal elemental deity. But only a rank lower than the Supreme Godhead Viṣṇu. So, although he is the deity of wind, he has bigger implications in Dvaita. This same Vāyu is said to have incarnated thrice as Hanumāna, Bhīma and then as Madhva in his Madhva's doctrine.