# Do followers of Madhwa consider him to be an incarnation of Vayu?

Tags: avatars, vayu, madhwa

Is that something he claimed himself? or did his followers consider his incarnation to be revealed in scripture?

Comment: More or less a duplicate:https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/do-scriptures-mention-about-srimad-madhvacharya-being-an-avatar-of-lord-vayu ..