# Where is Ramanujacharya's Jeeva Samadhi located?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya, samadhi

Where is Ramanujacharya's Jeeva Samadhi located? Is it located in Tamilnadu or anywhere else in India?

Comment: Do you mean did Shree Ramanuja took Jiva Samadhi or is his monuments (which is also called as samadhi sometimes.) is  present anywhere in T.N. or elsewhere

Comment: Yes sir please say where  is ramanjur charya jiva Samadhi I do not know where it is

Answer (score 4):

There is no Jeeva samadhi for Ramanujacharya. The actual body of Ramanujacharya is still preserved in Sri Rangam temple.  There is Udayavar Sannidhi. Udayavar is another name of Ramanujacharya conferred by Lord Ranganatha himself.

For more details on the mortal remains of the body, see  [How much does the divinely created statue of Ramanujacharya resemble him?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8031/5212)

[image: Mortal remain of Ramanujacharya at Udayavar Sannidhi, Sri Rangam]

Comment: Could you add more details on the picture you shared?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I added alt text for image. More details are present in the link I added above. That is a Q&A from our site itself. What details are you looking for?

Comment: Is it permitted by pancharatra agamas to preserve a body inside a temple?

Comment: @LazyLubber It is a special case. It's said that Ranganatha himself ordered to preserve in Vsantha Mandapam.

Comment: No sir one persons has said really ramanjur charya jeeva samadhi is there please search and say it for me it my humble request what really happend  in sri Rangam temple ramanjur body was buried what they have hidden the serect the iyers how do pooja for in temple they know the serect I have read in YouTube comments all people are saying the the ramanjur now is fake body this not his real body they have buried the body this true I have read in YouTube comments

Comment: According the priest whose family has been attending to the shrine of Sri Ramanuja at Srirangam for generations, Sri Ramanuja's body was buried below the shrine and an idol was installed above it. The idol itself is made of some kind of pulped wood/textile and requires periodic treatment to keep it preserved.  @user16581 It is not uncommon for an idol of the Lord to be installed in a sanyasin's 'brindavanam' (burial shrine). We have several such examples today such as the brindavanam of Sri Srinivasa Mahadesika Yati at Srirangam which houses a Lakshmi Narayana shrine.