# Benefits of Varanamayiram

Tags: puranas

Varanamayiram composed by Kodai Nachiyar is a classic one. What are the benefits a devotee can obtain by reciting this? Can selected slokas be recited every day?Answers not from wikipedia or divyadesam. Purana reference is must.

Comment: Since Andal is after the Puranas we won't find reference in them about her.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to answer this question since Andal alwar was born after the time of composition of Puranas by Veda Vyasa.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you won't find Puranic references to Andal ormthe Alwars except in the forms of prophecy, since most of the Alwars were born after the Puranas were written.  So if you want to know the benefits of reciting a particular Alwar pasuram, your best bet is to turn to the works of Sri Vaishnava Acharyas, not the Puranas.  Now thankfully the first Sri Vaishnava Acharya Nathamuni, who as I discussed in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3039/36) compiled the Alwars' poems into the Naalayira Divya Prabandham, composed a Phala Shruti for each poem outlining the benefits of reciting it.  [Here](http://dravidaveda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=855) is the Phala Shruti for Andal's Vaaranam Aayiram poem:

> AyanukkAha tAn kaNDa kanAvinai 
>   vEyar puhazh villiputtoor kOn kOdai Sol | 
>   tooya tamizh mAlai eeraindum vallavar 
>   vAyu nan makkaLai peTTru mahizhvarE ||
>
> This decad of pure Tamil verses by famous Villiputtur-king’s daughter Goda, describes her dream of marrying the cowherd-Lord. Those who sing it will be blest with good progeny.

That is why this poem is recited so often in weddings.

But that's not the only benefit of reciting it.  Ultimately the purpose of reciting the Alwars' poems is that they encourage devotion to Vishnu and thereby can lead a person to being united with the lotus feet of Sriman Narayana.

Let me also quote a [Taniyan](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/alvars/andal/nt/nt-taniyan2.html) or invocatory verse  which the first Sri Vaishnava Acharya of the Vanamamalai Matham (the Sri Vaishnava Matham I belong to) composed about the Nachiyar Thirumozhi, the collection of Andal's poems that Vaaranam Aayiram is a part of:

> kOlasuri Sangai mAyan sevvAyin guNam vinavum 
>   seelattinaL ten tirumalli nAdi, sezhunguzhal mel 
>   mAlait toDai ten arangarukkeeyum madippuDaiya 
>   sOlaikkiLi, avaL tooya naRpAdam tuNai namakke
>
> This taniyan states emphatically that only the sacred feet of ANDAL, whose sweet words resemble those of a garden parrot, and who brought greatness to the vEyar kulam of periyAzhwAr, are the refuge for us (today, tomorrow and for ever).

In any case, to answer your other question, yes, you can recite any Alwar Pasuram at any time; they don't have caste restrictions or other restrictions unlike the Vedas.

Comment: @KS-- Thanks for your effort. I was expecting in the following fashion--1. Reception of the bride groom (mApiLLai azhaippu, jAnavAsam)
2. Announcement of wedding ceremony (niscayatArtham)
3. Elders’ consent and Sister-in-law (nAttanAr kodi uduttal) to dressup the bride
4. Tying the holy string on hand (kAppu kaTTal or rakShA bandan)
5. Removing the obstacles (piDisuRRudal)
6. Holding the hands together (pAnigrahaNam)
7. Walking seven steps together, wedding vows (agni pradakShiNa, saptapati)

Comment: 8. Stepping on the stone (shilArohaNam, ammi midittal)
9. Offering of puffed rice (lAja hOmam, pori iDudal)
10. Sprinkling yellow holy water (manjaL nIr teLittal)
I needed the slokas how kodhai nachiyar has composed the hymns.

Comment: Nobody is  answering Vaishnavite type question except you. Why is it so?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Well, there's lots of Vaishnavas (and Shaivites and Smarthas) on this site, but some of the Vaishnavas are Gaudiya Vaishnavas rather than Sri Vaishnavas.  As far as I know there are only three Sri Vaishnavas who are currently active on the site: me, you, and the user [Krishna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/808/krishna).